# How to Provision APIs on Heroku

Tags: heroku, namecheap

Please forgive my question. I am a complete newbie at this.

I have built an API in spring boot and I have pushed it to heroku.

I have a custom domain for my website already as `www.mywebsite.com`

I want to provision my apis under this domain as well as `api.mywebsite.com`

How can I achieve this on heroku?

Any help on how to go about this would be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to add a custom domain to your existing web service running on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you have full access to the Namecheap account.

You have 2 options:
A. Use Heroku CLI
B. Use Heroku interface (Web application)

A) Let's go through the process with Heroku CLI.

1. Make sure that you have the Heroku CLI installed (macOS: `brew install heroku`, Ubuntu: `apt install heroku`, etc.)
2. Add your domain using the command `heroku domains:add api.website.com` (if you have multiple apps, don't forget at the end of the command to add `--app name-of-your-heroku-app`.
3. Heroku will generate for you a DNS target for the custom domain you added at step 2. Run `heroku domains` and copy the DNS target (The DNS target looks like this: `whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com`)
4. Open your Namecheap domain settings and add a CNAME (Name: "api" and Target: the DNS target provided by Heroku).
5. Wait few minutes up to few hours.

B) If you want to use Heroku Interface / Webapplications.

1. Open your app on [www.herokuapp.com](http://www.herokuapp.com)
2. Go to "Settings" tab
3. Scroll down to "Domains"
4. Click on "Add domains"
5. Add your subdomain (`api.website.com`)
6. Heroku will generate for you a DNS Target
7. Navigate to your domain settings in Namecheap and create a new CNAME using your subdomain (e.g. `api`) as name and the DNS target provided by Heroku as target.

You can find all the details in [Custom Domain Names for Apps Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)